# How to compare two comma-separated strings, and return TRUE if there is at least 1 match

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have to variables that contain comma-separated strings:

```
@v1 = 'hello, world, one, two'
@v2 = 'jump, down, yes, one'
```

I need a function that will return TRUE if there is at least one match.  So in the above example, it would return TRUE since the value 'one' is in both strings.

Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: Is it possible in SQL? Yes. Do you want to do this in SQL? Probably not. SQL Server is not that great with comma separated lists. You could write a function that splits the lists into tables and compare the two tables, not a very nice solution though.

Comment: You could do a SQL CLR function to get around the performance issues.

Answer (score 13):

Use a split function ([many examples here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) - CLR is going to be your best option in most cases back before SQL Server 2016 - now you should use `STRING_SPLIT()`).

Once you have a split function, the rest is quite easy. The model would be something like this:

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'hello, world, one, two',
        @v2 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'jump, down, yes, one';

SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.Split(@v1) AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.Split(@v2) AS b
    ON a.Item = b.Item
)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

You can even reduce this to only call the function once:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Split(@v1)
  WHERE ', ' + LTRIM(@v2) + ',' 
    LIKE '%, ' + LTRIM(Item) + ',%'
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

On 2016+:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM STRING_SPLIT(@v1, ',')
  WHERE ', ' + LTRIM(@v2) + ',' 
    LIKE '%, ' + LTRIM([Value]) + ',%'
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Comment: how can we modify this if we want to check whether all elements in v1 are exact match in all element in v2. Means both contain same elements then return return 1 OR 0

Comment: @BZT sounds like a different question, you should ask it (or search to see if it's already been asked, I suspect it has).

Answer (score -1):

You can use CTEs to split your string into xml nodes, then insert the words into table variables. Joining the table variables will reveal any matches

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(200) = 'hello, world, one, two'
DECLARE @v2 VARCHAR(200) = 'jump, down, yes, one'
DECLARE @v1Words TABLE (word VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @v2Words TABLE (word VARCHAR(100))

;WITH cteSplitV1 AS( 
SELECT CAST('<word>' + REPLACE(@v1,', ','</word><word>') + '</word>' AS XML) AS words) 
INSERT INTO @v1Words(word)
    SELECT word.x.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [word]
    FROM cteSplitV1
    CROSS APPLY words.nodes('/word') AS word(x)

;WITH cteSplitV2 AS( 
SELECT CAST('<word>' + REPLACE(@v2,', ','</word><word>') + '</word>' AS XML) AS words) 
INSERT INTO @v2Words(word)
    SELECT word.x.value('.','VARCHAR(100)') AS [word]
    FROM cteSplitV2 
    CROSS APPLY words.nodes('/word') AS word(x)

SELECT *
FROM @v1Words v1
JOIN @v2Words v2
    ON v1.word = v2.word
```